# R plot Google quickdraw

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to have some tips concerning an assignment I am working on, in R

The data example is a small subset of the sketches collected by Google quickdraw.
The data is already in flat format as needed for the models. I have to reformat them to the 2D  $28 \times 28$ pixel format to make a graph showing the sketches for these observation.

```
plf <- function(obs) {
  d1 <- matrix(sketches[obs,1:784], nrow=28, ncol=28) # obs= row number
  d1 <- as.data.frame(d1)
  d1$x <- rownames(d1)
  d1$x <- factor(d1$x, level=1:28)
  d1 <- pivot_longer(d1, cols = 1:28, names_to = "y", values_to = "z")
  d1$y <- rep(1:28, length.out=784)
  d1$y <- factor(d1$y, level=28:1)
  d1$z <- factor(d1$z, level=255:0)
  
  p <- ggplot(d1, aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z)) + 
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_grey() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
  print(p)
}

plf(128) # crab
```

Is there any other way to show the image in a better way? For some images the shape is not totally clear due to some pixels having different value

[image]

Comment: You could add `+ coord_equal()` to your plot to make the pixels square. Beyond that, it's not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: I wanted to add some "refinement" to the plot, but I suppose the data are like these and cannot do too much.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot anyway. now it looks better

Comment: `geom_raster()` is more efficient than `geom_tile()` if it is guaranteed that the observations are on a grid.